# setChecked(false) is the same as setChecked(true)?

Tags: android

I'm using `android:checkableBehavior="single"` within a `group`,  this group contains few items, those items represents content filters, there is no default filter(meaning there is not always has to be a checked item, at least that what I wants), if I click a filter and want to disable it I can click it again and my expectation is that by using `setChecked(false)` the item will unchecked.

However, [it looks like](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178709):

> For checkableBehavior="single" setChecked() will always check the menu
>   item even if parameter is 'false' because of Google implementation.

My obvious solution is adding a `no filter` item that can be checked by the users to indicates they don't want a filter but it's just seems more intuitive to check and uncheck the same item, it there another way to `setChecked(false)`?

Comment: use checkbox and manage checked / unchecked problematically

Comment: We definitely have a different idea about what's intuitive.

Comment: @EugenPechanec so you suggest the `no filter` option?

Comment: @AnandSavjani can you point me to some example...

Comment: Either No filter option or get rid of RadioGroup and handle (un)selecting other items by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's brain-dead implementation in `MenuItemImpl` (as of Nougat):

```
@Override
public MenuItem setChecked(boolean checked) {
    if ((mFlags & EXCLUSIVE) != 0) {
        // Call the method on the Menu since it knows about the others in this
        // exclusive checkable group
        mMenu.setExclusiveItemChecked(this);
    } else {
        setCheckedInt(checked);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Note that `checked` is completely ignored when the `EXCLUSIVE` flag is set.